# hibernate: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my class:

```
public class TrainLate {

private int id;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private Set<TrainSchedule> ts=new HashSet<TrainSchedule>(); 
public TrainLate(){}
public TrainLate(int id, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

    // setters and getters...
}
```

The type Date is `java.sql.Date`

In another class I use HQL:

```
String hql="SELECT new TrainLate(id,startDate,endDate) FROM TrainLate "+                "WHERE id="+String.valueOf(index);
```

where index is an int parameter.

Here is the "TrainLate.hbm.xml":

```
<class name="classes.TrainLate">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="startDate"/>
    <property name="endDate"/>
    <set name="ts"  lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
           <key column="trainLateID" />
           <one-to-many class="classes.TrainSchedule" />
          </set>  
</class>
```

Here is the exception:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [classes.TrainLate] [SELECT new TrainLate(id,startDate,endDate) FROM classes.TrainLate WHERE id=0]
```

Where "classes" is the package name.

Comment: I have solved the problem by changing sql.Date to util.Date and re-export the class to oracle and in oracle, type would be "timestamp". But if I use sql.Date in java, type would be "Date" in oracle after the export, and there would be the exception above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Hibernate requires your entities to have a default no argument constructor.

Second: Your hql should be: `"from TrainLate t where t.id = :id"`.

```
String hql = "from TrainLate t where t.id = :id";
List<TrainLate> result = (List<TrainLate>) session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("id", 1).list();
```

Or even better. When you know the id of the entity you don't need to search with hql:

```
TrainLate t = session.get(TrainLate.class, 1L); // I assume your id is a Long
```

This one returns `null` if the entity is not found.

or

```
TrainLate t = session.load(TrainLate.class, 1L); // I assume your id is a Long
```

This one throws an `ObjectNotFoundException` if the entity is not found.

Comment: I have the no argu constructor. Well I tried session.get() method and it works. But what's wrong with the HQL? And I have to use it in the next.

Comment: you usually use placeholders and don't compose the hql on the fly. HQL is suitable for the other non ids properties.

Comment: You mean placeholder like this?  Query query=session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("id", 0); It doesn't work either.

Comment: like in `where t.id = :id`. `:id` is a placeholder.

Comment: Strangely, I made it work yesterday with HQL, but today I change some other codes irrelevant, it doesn't work.

Comment: placeholder is also with the exception:Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [classes.TrainLate] [SELECT new TrainLate(id,startDate,endDate) FROM classes.TrainLate WHERE id=0]

Comment: You might have changed the date types? Did you clean up and then redeploy?

Comment: Thank you. After the exception, I changed the type of startDate and endDate in the database from "timestamp" to "Date". How to clean up and redeploy?

Comment: I have fixed it and made a comment below the question, thank u!

Answer (score 1):

I know it can sound silly, but have you tried to debug this thing?

My first thought would be (if I were hibernate :) ) to create an object of TrainLate with No-OP constructor and then invoke a series of setters to set id, startDate and endDate.

I didn't see it in your code snippet...